# Can I start with a passing unit test?

Tags: testing, tdd

[Uncle Bob's rules for TDD are specified here.](http://butunclebob.com/ArticleS.UncleBob.TheThreeRulesOfTdd)

1. You are not allowed to write any production code unless it is to
   make a failing unit test pass.
2. You are not allowed to write any more
   of a unit test than is sufficient to fail; and compilation failures
   are failures.
3. You are not allowed to write any more production code
   than is sufficient to pass the one failing unit test.

But, is it ok to write a bunch of tests that pass as soon as the test compiles?  For example, a test that asserts null and the default impl of a method I'm testing returns null.  Am I doing something wrong by doing this?  Should I skip to the first test that will fail or is it ok to write tests that automatically pass first?

Comment: Aside: some folks add the additional (sub)rule that the test should first fail *with a meaningful error message*.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

No, because it is possible to write a test that inadvertently passes when it should actually fail.

That's why you must make it fail *first,* so that you can demonstrate transitioning from a failed state to a passed state where you're testing the actual functionality that you want, rather than having a bogus test that passes and makes you think that your code actually works, when in fact it doesn't.

Comment: Won't I be showing that when I write the first test that fails without changing the impl?

Comment: I thought you said that you want your first test to pass.

Comment: It's not about *want*, I just happened to write a few tests that say, "given...when...then return null" and my production code implementation returns null.  My ide creates blank impls with `return null;` as a stub for me.

Comment: Throw an exception as placeholder, that way it'll always fail (unless you test for this specific exception). If you return null as a placeholder, but it's also valid implementation, you've already broken the rules.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel OK, but after the first test makes me change that exception to a `return null;`, if I write 2-3 more tests after that that also assert null, am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @tieTYT: If the very first test on a method happens to test for the stub-implementation that your IDE creates for a method, I would not worry too much. The initial compilation failure due to the missing method is also a test failure.

Comment: @BartvanIngenSchenau: Not really.  Without compilation, the test cannot be executed at all.  You cannot get a "red" result from a test that never runs.

Answer (score 19):

It depends.

If you are writing software to solve a business problem or produce a useful tool, then yes, you are allowed to write a test that passes automatically.

If, on the other hand, you are writing software in order to perform a religious observance at the First Denominational Church of TDD, then no, you are not allowed to do that. And you should probably take a moment of self-flagellation for even asking the question.

Comment: +1 : Excellent, so much truth spoken in such few words....

Comment: +1, great answer, I have to remember this for every case where one asks "do I have to follow some evangelists rules strictly"

Comment: TDD is so unintuitive I want to make sure I'm **strictly** following the practice before I decide if the practice is worth following.  If I took the attitude of, "This seems silly and I probably don't need to worry about it" I wouldn't have attempted TDD in the first place.  Even if I never strictly practice TDD, I think there's a lot of value in knowing how to strictly practice it.

Comment: @tieTYT: It will be less unintuitive if you think of TDD as part of your design process.  Because units tests require testable methods, the practice of creating the test first shapes the API and influences the way you write your code, in positive ways.

Comment: @tieTYT: I will admit that that's a fair point.

Comment: @tieTYT : Many current best practice methodologies were created by an evangelical 'big bang' (usually in some university by some academic who had obviously failed high school statistics and could not grasp the simple concept that 50% of developers are below average) and subsequently evolved into what is now called best practice. Those that failed to evolve, died (Darwinism at it's best).  TDD is still evolving. Further TDD is about as easy and practical to retrofit to existing applications as turning an F1 race car into a family people mover.